# React state variable availability

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I have my code sequence like below (its pseudo code just to explain flow)

```
useEffect(()=> { Load data from db and store it in state variable for isAllowed}

if(isAllowed)
 {
   return (<div>You are allowed</div);
 }
else
 {
   return (<div>Not allowed</div>);
```

The issue I am facing is, code reaches to if(isAllowed) condition and prints "Not allowed" due to the Async operation. Could you please explain me how to handle this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make it possible to distinguish between *three* situations, and not just two: allowed, not allowed, and not fetched yet. Try something like:

```
const [allowed, setAllowed] = useState(null);
useEffect(() => {
  // API call, eventually resulting in
  setAllowed(result.allowed);
  // setting allowed to either true or false
}, []);
return (
  <div>{
    allowed === null
      ? null // don't render anything yet
      : allowed
        ? 'You are allowed'
        : 'Not allowed'
  }</div>
);
```

You could also set the *text* to be rendered into state instead.

```
const [allowed, setAllowed] = useState('');
useEffect(() => {
  // API call, eventually resulting in
  setAllowed(
      result.allowed ? 'You are allowed' : 'Not allowed'
  );
}, []);
return (
  <div>{allowed}</div>
);
```

Comment: Thank you CertainPerformance, when I put a console.log(allowed), it prints it twice. Any idea why the code is called twice? Is it ok to do so?

Comment: That's to be expected, if you're logging in the main component function body. The component will render initially, resulting in a log. Then the API request will occur, the state will be updated, and the component will re-render, resulting in the function running again and a new log occurring.

Comment: OK got it. But If I remove the log, will it still happen? and cause any performance issues?

Comment: If you remove the log, nothing should be logged, and it should be just fine. No, re-rendering components generally does not cause any performance issues.